My .py file works perfectly, but when I turn it to .exe it fails
I'm trying to code an app that lets you download many videos (or audios) from Youtube at the same time using Python, specifically the libraries tkinter and pytube. When I run it as a .py file, everything goes perfect. However, when I turn it into a .exe (using auto-py-to-exe), there's a problem, although everything else works, the "Download" Button does absolutely nothing.
I want to clarify, when I press the "Downlaod" button no error pops up, it just doesn't work.
Here's the whole code.
# importing packages 
from pytube import YouTube 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox

WIDTH = "500"
HEIGHT = "300"

dir = ""
url_list = []

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry(WIDTH + "x" + HEIGHT)
root.resizable(False, True)
root.title("Youtube Downloader")

audio = tk.BooleanVar()
single_song = tk.BooleanVar()

def download(url, dir, audio):
    yt = YouTube(url=url)
    if audio.get(): 
        video = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
    else:
        video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    video.download(output_path=dir) 

    if single_song.get():
        messagebox.showinfo("Done", yt.title + " has been successfully downloaded.")

def change_value(var):
    if var:
        var = False
    else:
        var = True

def get_dir():
    global dir  
    dir = filedialog.askdirectory()

def add(url):
    global url_list
    url_list.append(url)

def display():    
    global url_list
    for child in frm_disp.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
    for url in url_list:
        label = tk.Label(frm_disp, text=url)
        label.pack()

def clear():
    global url_list
    url_list = []
    for child in frm_disp.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()

def download_all(dir, audio):
    global url_list 
    if len(url_list) == 0:
        messagebox.showwarning("URL","Please write a URL")
        return
    if dir == "":
        messagebox.showwarning("Directory", "Please select a directory")
        return
    
    for url in url_list:
        download(url, dir, audio)

    messagebox.showinfo("Done", "All songs downloaded correctly")

frm = tk.Frame(root, width=480, height=480)
frm.pack()

lbl = tk.Label(root, text="List of songs to be donwloaded (Press \"Display\" to refresh):", pady=10)
lbl.pack()

frm_disp = tk.Frame(root, width=480, height=100, highlightthickness=2,highlightbackground="black")
frm_disp.pack()

btsingle_song = tk.Checkbutton(root, variable=single_song, text="Warn when each song has been downloaded")
btsingle_song.pack()

guide = tk.Label(frm, text="Write the URL of the Youtube video:")
guide.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3,pady=10)

bturl = tk.Entry(frm, width=75)
bturl.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)

dwn = tk.Button(frm, command= lambda: download_all(dir, audio), width=15, text="Download")
dwn.grid(row=2, column=1)

btdir = tk.Button(frm, command=get_dir, width=15, text="Directory")
btdir.grid(row=2, column=0)

btadd = tk.Button(frm, command= lambda: add(bturl.get()), width=15, text="Add")
btadd.grid(row=3, column=0)

disp = tk.Button(frm, command=display, width=15, text="Display")
disp.grid(row=3, column=1)

clr = tk.Button(frm, command=clear, width=15, text="Clear")
clr.grid(row=3, column=2)

only_audio = tk.Checkbutton(frm, text="Only audio (as mp3)", variable=audio)
only_audio.grid(row=2, column=2)

root.update()
root.mainloop()



I have tried to attach the folders in auto-py-to-exe to see if the modules were the problem, but It didn't work. I've also tried running it in a virtual environment that has pytube installed (as it is not installed on my machine, it is installed on an env), but it didn't work either.
As the only problem is the "Download" button I've thought that maybe pytube is the problem, but I've got no idea.
Update:
I kept testing the code and whenever I try to download a video or audio, it throws the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
  File "DonwloadYoutube.py", line 93, in <lambda>
  File "DonwloadYoutube.py", line 71, in download_all
  File "DonwloadYoutube.py", line 27, in download
  File "pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
  File "pytube\__main__.py", line 181, in fmt_streams
  File "pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
  File "pytube\cipher.py", line 30, in __init__
  File "re.py", line 252, in compile
  File "re.py", line 304, in _compile
  File "sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
  File "sre_parse.py", line 950, in parse
  File "sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
  File "sre_parse.py", line 668, in _parse
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 2

I've also tested the executable in other machines and it throws this error too, although when I run the code it always works.

If I take your script and put it in a new project with only pytube and auto-py-to-exe installed, the script works and auto-py-to-exe succeeds in packaging it. When I run the resulting executable, it works just as well as the script, without creating a virtual environment to run it from. There must be something additional that you're not mentioning here. I would recommend trying to repeat the process cleanly, and find out what is different in your original setup. (I was using Python 3.11 on Windows 10) Edit: the issue does occur when you use the 'one file' option.

Your code works fine for me using pytube2 15.0.6 and python 3.12.3 even after generating an executable using PyInstaller 6.8.0.

what means there's a problem? Did you run .exe in console/terminal to see error messages? Error messages may show you what is wrong. Sometimes it may have problem to find some Python module or C/C++ library because it didn't find it when it was creating .exe - and it may need to add this module manually to file .spec before creating .exe. But this problem you can see in most questions about pyinstaller. maybe if you would first  read some questions and answers then you would resolve it without asking question

if something doesn't work then maybe add some print() to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables , create .exe, and run .exe in console/terminal to see these information. It is called print debugging and it can helps to see problem.
